# python manage.py migrate command gives ImportError: No module named django.core.management

Tags: python, django

I am a complete newbie to Python and Django and have been spending the last couple of days setting up MySQL, Python and now Django on a Windows 8 64-bit machine.

I have got as far as installing Django1.7 and creating the first project "mysite" and set up the DB connection to MySQL (I think).

I then hit problems trying to execute: python manage.py migrate but I get the ImportError: No module named django.core.management.

I have read a number of answers which mention ImportError: No module named django.core.management however none of them help me sort out my problem so I am hoping someone can help.

I am sure you need more info than this to resolve but I am not sure what is relevant. So if you can let me know what you need I'll fill in the blanks.

thanks
Nick

Comment: How did you install Django and what steps did you take to create the project?

Comment: I doubts you haven't added site-packages into path

Comment: Do you remember creating a virtualenv during the installation steps? If yes, you might have forgotten to activate it.

Comment: Does `python manage.py runserver` do any thing for you?